# Using a struct across classes in c++

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am still fairly new to c++ so please allow!
Essentially I have created a struct in the header file for one of my classes full of strings.

```
typedef struct details{
        string name;
        string address;
}details;
```

and I wish to not only use this struct in the cpp file that belongs to the header, but in other classes as well. For example, I want to create a vector of this struct in another header file.

```
private:
vector <details> foo;
```

I also want to use the struct in the main

```
details d;
d.name = "hi";
d.address = "hello";
```

however when I currently try to do this I get errors such as

```
error: 'details' was not declared in this scope
     vector <details> foo;
```

and

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
     vector <details> foo;
```

has anyone had similar issues who can provide insite into what I can do to fix this? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT TO DEMONSTRATE CODE**

class1.h

```
#include "class2.h"

struct trans1{
    string name;
};
class class1 {

private:
    vector <trans2> t2;

public:
    class1();
};
```

class2.h

```
#include "class1.h"

struct trans2{
    string type;
};

class class2{

private:
    vector <trans1> t1;

public:
    class2();
};
```

errorlog:

```
In file included from class1.h:3:0,
                 from class1.cpp:1:
class2.h:21:13: error: 'trans1' was not declared in this scope
     vector <trans1> t1;
             ^
class2.h:21:19: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     vector <trans1> t1;
                   ^
class2.h:21:19: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

I understand that this is ridiculous code in a real world application however this is the simplest way I could demonstrate

Comment: You have to include this header in each cpp module that refers to the structure.

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE.

Comment: Ive added code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the header file that contains the definition of the `struct` everywhere you use it.

The only cases where you don't have to is when you are only declaring references or pointers to it; in that case you can just forward declare it with:

```
struct details;
```

Also in C++ you can just declare it with:

```
struct details{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};
```

There's really no need for the `typedef`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ > The only cases where you don't have to is when you are only declaring references or pointers to it; in that case you can just forward declare it

Comment: @Jefffrey: unique_ptr, too. But not auto_ptr, for example.

Answer (score 2):

> details.h

```
#include <string>

#ifndef DETAILS_H
#define DETAILS_H

struct details {
  std::string name;
  std::string address;
};

#endif
```

> details.cpp

```
#include "details.h"
//insert implementation here
```

> other_header.cpp

```
#include "details.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<details> main_use;
//whatever else here
```

This should work.

**EDIT**

If you want to use it in another class:

> my_class.h

```
#include "details.h"
#include <vector>

#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class myClass {
std::vector<details> class_use;
//insert stuff here

};

#endif
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm pretty unsure why you define the structs in the classes as you do -- it is kind of confusing. Here's how I would do if. Note the `#ifndef ... #define ... #endif` pattern **is very important**. It's also a bad idea to include headers that include themselves. I would organize your code (as you have it) in the following way:

> trans.h

```
#ifndef TRANS_H 
#define TRANS_H

#include <string>
struct trans1 {
   std::string name;
};

struct trans2 {
   std::string type;
};

#endif
```

> class1.h

```
 #ifndef CLASS1_H
 #define CLASS1_H

 #include "trans.h"
 #include <vector>

 class Class1 {
   public:
     Class1();
   private:
     std::vector<trans2> t2;
 };

 #endif
```

> class2.h

```
 #ifndef CLASS2_H
 #define CLASS2_H

 #include "trans.h"
 #include <vector>

 class Class2 {
   public:
     Class2();
   private:
     std::vector<trans1> t1;
 };

 #endif
```

Now the way it's organized, you can use the `trans` struct by `#include "trans.h"`'ing in the main, along with eliminating the circular includes. Hope this helped.

You'll find that main.cc below compiles without error now.

> main.cc

```
#include<iostream>
#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"
#include "trans.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

erip

Comment: I have included the header files but have received a different error:
In file included from class.h:3:0,
library.h:22:13: error: 'newClass' was not declared in this scope
     vector <newClass> nC;

Comment: So the same error but this time with a class. I have included all headers in every class. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: You said you need a vector of structs, not a vector of classes. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes I also have a vector of type class, which throws the same error even with the header files in the correct position.

Comment: Post the minimum code needed to recreate this error in an edit.. I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The struct definition in c++ looks like

```
 #include <string>

 struct details{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
 };
```

and must be seen before it's used elsewhere in your code. Assumed you placed the declaration from above in a header file `details.hpp`, you should have the following to use it

```
 #include <vector>
 #include "details.hpp"

 // Some context

 std::vector<details> vdetails;
```

In certain situations, when the `details` struct members aren't actually accessed, you can also use a forward declaration as

```
 struct details;
```

instead of in including the complete struct declaration. This can be used then, to declare `details*` pointers or `details&` references in further declarations, as long there's nothing dereferenced with them.