# How come I can use a forward-declared class in a std::vector?

Tags: c++

I thought that you could only create a reference or pointer member to a forward-declared class. However, I was surprised to discover this works:

```
#include <vector>

struct Donkey;

struct Cage
{
    std::vector<Donkey> donkeys;
};

struct Donkey
{
};

int main()
{
    Cage c;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EP0zKR

How come `std::vector` can be defined with a forward-declared class? Is this standard?

Comment: Because the vector basically contains a pointer to the type (and size/capacity and maybe some other stuff), but the important part here is the pointer. You don't need the complete definition of a type to declare a pointer of the type, that's why it works.

Comment: internally std::vector has a pointer to donkey, so you're still only defining a reference or pointer member to a forward declared class.

Comment: Template type parameters don't generally have to be complete types. However, this particular template requires that your type be complete, and your program is ill-formed.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672135/why-c-containers-dont-allow-incomplete-types

Comment: @Praetorian: How is "why does vector allow its element to be an incomplete type" a _duplicate_ of "why does vector **not** allow its element to be an incomplete type"? lol. It could not be more opposite.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I guess it does answer my question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Opposite" only because Neil made an incorrect assumption and worded his question accordingly. I didn't use the dupe hammer because of that difference in wording. Quite clearly even you agree that the answer to that question answers this one too :)

Comment: @Praetorian: Yeah but I don't always agree that similar answers = duplicate question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Actually, you can't.**

Just because your program compiles (which is down to facts of the underlying implementation) does not mean it is valid.

[There *are* times other than declaring a `T*` or a `T&` at which you may use a forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/560648); it's just that [this is not one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18672135/560648).

Comment: Note that this is no longer true in C++17. [\[`std::vector`\] (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [The default allocator satisfies allocator completeness requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: @nwp: Interesting. Without doing a deep dive on that change I'd be worried about relying on this before I'd cleared up in my head when the destructor (a member!) is and is not instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined behavior.

> [C++14/§17.6.4.8] 1 In certain cases (replacement functions, handler
>   functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library
>   template components), the C++ standard library depends on components
>   supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their
>   requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the
>   implementation.
>
> [C++14/§17.6.4.8] 2 In particular, the effects are undefined in the
>   following cases: [...]
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>     that component.

Furthermore, an incomplete type doesn't meet the allocator requirements:

> [C++14/§17.6.3.5] 9 An allocator may constrain the types on which it
>   can be instantiated and the arguments for which its construct member
>   may be called. If a type cannot be used with a particular allocator,
>   the allocator class or the call to construct may fail to instantiate.

Because your class has a definition by the time the vector is instantiated, it's fine. Be on the lookout for this proposal which will change allocator requirements, [N4056 Minimal incomplete type support for standard containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4056.html)

Comment: "It's undefined behavior." "Because your class has a definition by the time the vector is instantiated, it's fine." Which is it?

Comment: welcome to the wacky world of standards committee members' arguments ;)